# SSRS Referencing variable on a filter

Tags: reporting-services, filter

I am trying to reference a variable as my filter for date. But it wont allow me. I get this error:

> A filter expression for the tablix includes a variable reference.
>   Variable values cannot be used in tablix filter expressions.

Can someone provide an alternative please? I cannot hard code the dates as my report will change every time it is run.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I used was to use a parameter in the same way i would have used a variable. This seemed to work for me.